# HTML5 web audio API wavesurfer.js crashes on large mp3 files

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I was planning on using wavesurfer.js in a project of mine so I checked out the demo on http://wavesurfer-js.org

I dropped a large mp3 file (around 2 hours) onto the middle of the page that asks for a file. It seems to want to load it but after a while Chrome comes up with an error. It doesnt crash, just the tab fails.

With smaller files, single songs, it seems to work ok.

So there seems to be either some limitations with html5 web audio or the websurfer.js library but im not sure. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[wavesurfer.js GitHub: Large MP3 files cause DOM Exception 12](https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/issues/9)

> Sorry that it takes so long to resolve this. From what I managed to google, Safari and Chrome can't decode a large binary due to memory limits.

It looks like it can't be fixed right now, perhaps in the future. They're trying other approaches but without success so far.